# Twisted server returning text with unexpected fonts

Tags: python, fonts, twisted, twisted.web

My current twisted server code. It is a simple experiment to take url encoded requests and convert them into a JSON like string to then return.

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor
import urllib.parse

class FormPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        print(request.uri)
        x = (request.uri).decode('ascii')
        x = x[1:]
        x = todi(x)
        return x.encode('ascii')
def todi(st):
    if len(st) == 0:
        return '{}'
    if st[len(st)-1] == '/':
        st = st[:-1]
    if len(st) == 0:
        return '()'
    if st[0] == '?':
        st = st[1:]
    st = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(st)
    return str(dict(st))



factory = Site(FormPage())
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
reactor.run()
```

I've paid attention to the font my browser displays when I am receiving simple text. For example this site: http://icanhazip.com/ when you visit, the font looks like `consola` font (default font for MS notepad). However, when I visit my site, my browser displays a font that looks like `Times New Roman`.

I have done some debugging since, such as forcing the site to return a simple string of characters, but nothing can stop twisted from giving me ugly looking fonts.

Here, have an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyei6.jpg).

Also note that I did the thing in Chrome where you right click and use the "View page source" button. Trust me, both my examples are simply raw text according to that.

Comment: What does it look like if your twisted server returns exactly the same IP address string as http://icanhazip.com/ does? These should render the same and it has nothing to do with Twisted at all.

Comment: Somehow they don't look the same.

Comment: so you have tried _exactly_ the same string? Make your `render()` function like this: `def render_GET(self, request): return '123.123.123.123'` (replace `123.123.123.123` with the same IP address displayed by http://icanhazip.com

Comment: Yup. Done exactly that. Also note I did mention maybe it was a bit vague I had to return a bytes like object so that involved a doing `.encode('ascii')` or `b'text'` but the font is still different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the headers returned by your Twisted server and comparing them to those returned by the other web site, the latter specifies `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`, whereas the Twisted server does not specify the `Content-Type` at all.

Your browser (and I've found it to be the same with Firefox) uses a different font when the content type is specified as `text/plain` vs. an unspecified content type.

In Twisted you can set the `Content-Type` header with [`request.setHeader()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.http.Request.html#setHeader) like this:

```
def render_GET(self, request):
    print(request.uri)
    x = (request.uri).decode('ascii')
    x = x[1:]
    x = todi(x)
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8')
    return x.encode('UTF-8')
```

As this sets the `Content-Type` it might as well specify the charset too. UTF-8 is (probably) preferred, and the response text is similarly encoded.